Stripe signature verification exception error PHP
I’m trying to implement the Stripe payment intent payment method into my application. So far the payments go through but the webhook gives me the following exception error: 
Image of error
Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

This is my code setup: 
    public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
    {
        $sPayload = json_decode($request->getContent());
        $sSignature = $request->header('Stripe-Signature');
        $sWebhookSecret = env('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET');

        $oPaymentIntentResponse = Webhook::constructEvent(
             json_encode($sPayload), $sSignature, $sWebhookSecret
        );

        $this->processPaymentIntentFeedback($oPaymentIntentResponse);

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }


￼
This all is using a live webhook.
Image of webhook
￼
I get the stripe webhook secret key from this wehbook.
The stripe key and secret I get from this same application.
So the keys should all be in order. The webhook is found and the payments go through the only issue is that the signature is not validated.
Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

The payload, signature, and webhook signature in my code get delivered correctly they just don’t seem to match. What could be going wrong?

If the webhook signing secret (whsec_xxx) is correct, then you'd expect to see this error if the payload or signature are being parsed by your framework and altered somehow.
Does using $sPayload = @file_get_contents('php://input') and $sSignature = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']; improve this situation? https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks/quickstart?lang=php

Stripe's constructEvent function is very sensitive, any changes to whitespace in the original Event content will cause a shift in the calculated signature value and lead to signature not found errors. I believe the way you're decoding then re-encoding the request's payload.
I'd suggest trying to pass the raw request payload into constructEvent rather than try to use the already processed value.
Swapping this:
$oPaymentIntentResponse = Webhook::constructEvent(
             json_encode($sPayload), $sSignature, $sWebhookSecret
        );

for:
$oPaymentIntentResponse = Webhook::constructEvent(
             $request->getContent(), $sSignature, $sWebhookSecret
        );

That's closer to what Stripe recommends in their example webhook endpoint code:
https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks/quickstart?lang=php
